# Can School Download Visual Studio Code for Free?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am planning to use Visual Studio Code in school. And I am worried if there is any payment for schools to download Visual Studio Code. Since I want to get VS code for free. Because sometimes there are some programs which allows private account to download the program for free but has to pay when organization like school wants to download the program.

Comment: It is free..... https://code.visualstudio.com/

Comment: Hi @BlahBlah. Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site is dedicated to discussion of issues about code, so this question is not really appropriate here. Product pricing discussions would be better suited to some of the other Stack Exchange sites (see https://stackexchange.com/sites).

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good question. The answer can be easily found by Google.
Check [Visual Studio Code Official Website Q&A](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/FAQ#_is-vs-code-free),
there's dirct answer to your question.

> #### Is VS Code free?
>
> Yes, VS Code is free for private or commercial use. See the product license for details.